# Neoforce Event Handler not firing

Tags: c#, xna, event-handling, xna-4.0

I have created an XNA project and am trying to implement the [Neoforce Library](https://github.com/NeoforceControls/XNA), but I cannot get the `Button.Click` event to fire.

Here's my code:

```
button = new Button(manager);
button.Init();
this.button.Click += new TomShane.Neoforce.Controls.EventHandler(this.button_Click);
button.Text = "Sign In";
button.Width = 72;
button.Height = 24;
button.Left = (main.ClientWidth / 2) - (button.Width / 2);
button.Top = main.ClientHeight - button.Height - 8;
button.Anchor = Anchors.Bottom;
button.Parent = main;
button.Visible = true;

manager.Add(button); 
main.Add(button, true);
```

My event's code is:

```
void button_Click(object sender, TomShane.Neoforce.Controls.EventArgs e) {
    System.Console.Out.WriteLine("Button Clicked");
}
```

Everything is displayed fine, however the event will simply not fire.

Comment: i guess you have to check if is clicked in your update function.

Comment: Have you tried to see if any other events, such as MouseOver, MouseOut, etc work? Why are you using `this.button` instead of `button`? Those could be 2 different objects.

Comment: In addition, do you see the slight glow when you hover over the button? Make sure you are calling `base.Update(gameTime)` from your update method, to update Neoforce. (Assuming you are inheriting from `Application`)

Comment: @Cyral I have tried those events and I have tried this.button too, as for base.Update. Well, there is no overload for base.Update(gameTime) that takes only 1 argument, so we run base.Update(gameTime, otherScreenHasFocus, false); and that has always been running before we installed Neoforce. We are also using XNA 4.0 if that helps

Comment: @Cyral I thought about what you said(about calling the update) and I found that I have to run manager.Update(gameTime) in the Update method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Update method, you must run the manager Update method. Like so:

```
manager.Update(gameTime);
```

Thanks to Cyral, for giving me the idea to check for this.